# issue on Adding Multi Text To Chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

can you please take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/24WVg/1/) and let me know why I am not able to add multi text to a the chart in one function?

I used this function

```
function(chart) { 
       chart.renderer.text('Papa 1', 90, 60)
       chart.renderer.text('Papa 2', 140, 90)
            .attr({
                rotation: -0
            })
            .css({
                color: '#B8B6B6',
                fontSize: '12px'
            })
            .add();
    });
```

but it is adding just the last text to the chart. Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can have both (or more than two text) to the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the first one. Change the first text to : `chart.renderer.text('Papa 1', 90, 60).add();`

```
function(chart) { 
       chart.renderer.text('Papa 1', 90, 60).add();
       chart.renderer.text('Papa 2', 140, 90)
            .attr({
                rotation: -0
            })
            .css({
                color: '#B8B6B6',
                fontSize: '12px'
            })
            .add();
    });
```